# Java Sort Collection on two expressions

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class

```
public class User {

    String country;
    Double rating;
    Double status;
}
```

I need to sort a List of this class based on two conditions.

At the start of the list needs to be Users which have a certain value for country. These users sort on rating. If rating is same, compare status.

If User has another value for country, just sort it on rating.

I have tried many attempts, and this is the most recent:

```
 final String country = me.getCountry();
 Collections.sort(usersArray, new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
                User user1 = lhs.getUser();
                String country1 = user1.getCountry();

                int result = country.equals(country1) ? 1 : 0;

                if (result == 0) {
                    result = Double.compare(lhs.rating, rhs.rating);
                    if (result == 0) {
                        return Double.compare(lhs.status, rhs.status);
                    } else
                        return result;
                }
                return Double.compare(lhs.rating, rhs.rating);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Not all Collection implementations are/can be ordered

Comment: Why do you use Double.compare() on int values ?

Comment: int result = country.compareTo(country1 == null ? "zzzzzzzz" : country1); this appears incorrect. You stated that you wanted people from your country at the top. This will sort the list by country alphabetically. Correctly implemented, this should be `int result = country.equals(country1) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @Kami is a pseudocode. In real code is a double values.

Comment: `Collections.sort(usersArray, new Comparator<ExpertData>() ` . Isn't ExpertData supposed to be ` new Comparator<User>` ?

Comment: @nanunanu-ney yes. thank you. corrected.

Comment: @Kami problem in country. The users which have another country value, not my - located at top.

Comment: @ssh sorry my comment was incorrect so I deleted it.

Comment: @ControlAltDel not working.

Comment: @VivinPaliath The users which have another country value, not my - located at top.

Comment: @ssh what does this line do `User user1 = lhs.getUser();` if **lhs** is alread an `User` what is the meaning of this call ?

Comment: @Kami is itself link.

Comment: @ssh as side note you don' t need that.  because `lhs`is the User itself

Comment: @Kami it doesn't matter. Problem in comparation.

Answer (score 0):

> The users which have another country value, not my - located at top

This happens because if countries are equal you return 1; otherwise you check rating/status. If one of these comparison return 1 then your Comparator also return 1. So countries are not equal but user from not your country has greater rating and Comparator return 1. That's why list is not sorted properly.

```
int result = country.equals(country1) ? 1 : 0; // DEBUG result = 0 

if (result == 0) { # DEBUG enter
    result = Double.compare(lhs.rating, rhs.rating); // DEBUG result = 1
    if (result == 0) {
        result = Double.compare(lhs.status, rhs.status);
    } else
        return result; // this could be omitted
}

return result; // DEBUG method return 1.
```

---

**After edit:**

You have to specify all possible situation:

1. country can be your or not (2 situations)
2. rating can be greater, equal, lower (3 situations)
3. status can be greater, equal, lower (3 situations)

If I calculated correctly (probability is not my strongest side) you have 18 situations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). You tell it which fields to compare in which order and it does the rest. Less code for you, too.

```
     return new CompareToBuilder()
       .append(lhs.country, rhs.country)
       .append(lhs.rating, rhs.rating)
       .append(lhs.status, rhs.status)
       .toComparison();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams from Java 8, you can do this:

```
Arrays.stream(usersArray)
      .sorted((lhs, rhs) -> Double.compare(lhs.status, rhs.status))
      .sorted((lhs, rhs) -> Double.compare(lhs.rating, rhs.rating))
      .toArray(size -> new User[size])
```

Because the resulting stream from the array is **ordered**, Java guarantees that the sorting is **stable**. This means that the order of the statuses is kept stable when the ratings are equal. This is why I first sort on status, then on ratings.

By the way, this approach does not change the order of the original array. It returns a new one.